# Where can I find other sources of Armor and Weapons?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm no longer satisfied with the weapons and armor available to me. I always end up playing with the gun model from Player's Handbook, and armor with the same AC and properties. Besides this material (PHB), what other sources are there for new armor and weapon types?

Comment: What genre of armour/weapons are you looking for?

Answer (score 8):

**Just about every book has new weapons**

No, seriously. Almost every supplement has new weapons, new armor, new magical versions of both, and usually new spells (though admittedly spells aren't relevant here). Some items of interest include:

- Magic Item Compendium (Magic weapons)
- Arms and Equipment Guide (everything)
- Any of the "Races of..." books. They all include new Exotic weapons associated with particular races, some of them rather infamous in optimization circles (skiprocks!)
- Libris Mortis (weapons and armor both pro and anti-undead)
- Complete Warrior
- Complete Adventurer
- Any campaign setting core book (like the Player's Guide to Faerun or the Eberron Campaign Setting)

Beyond that you'll find weapons tucked into nooks and crannies of just about any book, sometimes hidden in monster entries in the various Monster Manuals, other times in a small section of their own.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a source for weapons and armor there are a number of good sources.

If you're looking for web resources of where to find stuff there are these websites:

[Roleplay Nexus Armors](http://www.roleplaynexus.com/armorlist.html) (A list of most mundane armor in 3.5, though none of it has referenced the book source so if you find something you're interested in you're gonna have to hunt down where it's from)

[Ginormous List of Weapons](http://rodriguezvaughn.com/geekspeak/index.php?topic=133.0) (A huge list of weapons spanning tons of offical material from the completes to dragon magazine. Has references to what book the item can be found in but the formating is a little hard on the eyes.

If you're wanting actual books to read through, these here have good sections on weapons and armor:

[Magic Item Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/35magic) (Weapon and Armor Properties)

[Arms and Equipment Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/078692649X) (Mundane Armor, Weapons, and Adventuring Equipment)

[Races of Stone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786932783) (New types of Heavy and Exotic Armor)

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider checking out Bastion Press' "Arms & Armor 3.5" - it's out of print, but I'm pretty sure someone is still selling the PDF on RPGnow (I would give a direct link, but the server over there isn't responding right now).

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3.5e_Equipment
Plenty of homebrew armor, weapons, and other items, although I wouldn't suggest using some of them.